# SSIS package failing from SQLagent

Tags: ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a scheduled SQL job, it runs a SSIS package. The package contains a script task. I have faced on issue that SqlAgent is unable to trigger the package. After lot of investigation I could not find a direct solution and did a work around to execute the package through operating systems(cmdexe) step rather than sql server integration services type step. Now its running fine. However sometimes the job is failing and in the logs its throwing some error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." by script task. This is issue is coming randomly. when I run the same package manually from integration services catalog its running fine. But why is this happening only with SQlAgent that too sometimes??. Did anyone ever faced this issue. Please help.

Comment: What SSIS deployment method you are using? Is it file system deployment, Catalog based or Server based?

Comment: This error is far too general for us to be able to offer help when it happens randomly.   It could be too many things.   Maybe the code is perfect and it's server- or network- related.   Try putting detailed error handling and logging in your script task and see if you can pinpoint the culprit line of code.

Comment: Probably your code in ScriptTask uses something that SQL Agent Account does not have access to like (file, network share or Connection to database with Integrated Security).